# How do I generate a RouteLink to a route in a different area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-3.5

I have two different areas, and I have a route in one of those areas that is specific to that area, but I need to generate a link to that route using Html.RouteLink from another area (it's how you get over into the new area) but it won't work... It doesn't seem possible to use RouteLink to routes in a different area.

What is the best way around this? Should I just define a new route in the other area and name it differently?

**UPDATE (code):**

In master page in the main area (I've tried it multiple ways, all of which have produced same result):

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "CustomerSite", route = "CustomerSite_preview", domain = (string)ViewData["DomainName"] }, null) %>">
```

In the CustomerSite area registration as the first route registered:

```
        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "CustomerSite_preview",
            "preview/{domain}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { area = "CustomerSite", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
            new { isCustomerSite = new CustomerSiteRouteConstraint() },
            new string[] { "GrayHills.CarLotHosting.Web.Areas.CustomerSite.Controllers" }
        );
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be so difficult... I don't understand

Comment: Can you post your code? I use RouteLink and it works fine.

Comment: RouteLink works fine as long as you're creating a link to an area you're in, but not to a different area... I'll post my code after a while

Comment: Whats the error - I have used `Url.Action` from a masterpage and it works fine, similar to your setup(except for the RouteConstraint) with my URLs looking like `http://localhost:56291/preview/somedomain/Home?route=CustomerSite_preview`. `Html.RouteLink("Test", "CustomerSite_preview",new{domain="somedomain.com"}) -> http://localhost:56291/preview/somedomain.com`  
What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the method just always returns the url of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

In your route object you just need a property named area with the name of the area.

```
Html.RouteLink("My Link Text", 
                new { area = "MyArea", controller = "MyController" ... }, 
               null);
```

Comment: I have that. It doesn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure if its just something with the `RouteLink` method then, but have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx and consider using `ActionLink` instead?

Comment: It's a customized route: example.com/preview/somedomain.com/ so I don't think actionlink can do that

Comment: It should be able to do that.  You can specify anything you have a listed as a value in your route.  If your route is for an area called preview, you could make a route like `"preview/{url}"` and when you specify the route, your object would would look something like `new { area = "preview", url = previewStringVariable }`.

Comment: Just make sure you put that route before the catch all route.

Comment: It is, but still doesn't work... and doesn't matter if route is in the area or in the root "area", it still doesn't work... so confused!

Comment: Looking at the comment, it seems that Preview is your area, so what is the route configurations for this area?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your route definition - see the answer [ASP.NET MVC Url.Action routing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298422/asp-net-mvc-url-action-routing-error) for more info.

In essence, your route should look as follows since you explicitly supply the controller name and action:

```
context.MapRouteLowercase(
        "CustomerSite_preview",
        "preview/{domain}/home/index/",
        new {   area = "CustomerSite"
              , controller = "Home"
              , action = "Index"},
        new { isCustomerSite = new CustomerSiteRouteConstraint() },
        new string[] { 
            "GrayHills.CarLotHosting.Web.Areas.CustomerSite.Controllers"}
```

The Url.Action will look like

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Index"
                        , new {domain = (string)ViewData["DomainName"] }
                        , null) %>">
```

which will result in a Url like `http://localhost:56291/preview/somedomainname/home/index`